# Accessing persistance file from another project

Tags: jpa, persistence, ejb, ear

I have an EJB project setup in the following way

```
EAR Project
    EJB Proj
    EJB Client Proj
    JPA Proj
    Web Proj
```

I am in current need to use the persistance.xml file from the JPA proj to query the db from a servlet (in the web proj)

What would be the best way to gain access to this? 
Thanks
Jon

Comment: Why do you need access to the persistence.xml file? To get database details and then manually query the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need persistance.xml file to get the access to database connection.
In the web project you can get database connection by JNDI lookup.

Try something:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();<br>
Connection con = ((DataSource)ctx.lookup("Con-Pool-Name")).getConnection();
```